# How to open google worksheet based on name?

Tags: python, gspread

I am trying to open a google worksheet based on its name.

I have found this:

`gc.open('MySpreadSheet').sheet1`

However I am looking for a method to open it based on worksheet name instead than on `sheet1`

Answer (score 0):

A way of doing this:

```
ss= gc.open('MySpreadSheet')
ws = ss.worksheet('MyWorkSheet')
```